# Opening ports to Azure Web Job

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-webjobs

I have a requirement where I need to host an FTP server along with a website that is hosted on Azure Web Sites. We host separate instances of this app for our clients - and it needs an separate FTP server per instance

The solution that I'm trying currently is using the FubarDev.FtpServer. My plan was to host that FTP service in a web job.

Launching the FTP server seems ok. The Web Job prints out a line to web job console after the server is started, status is of the web job is running and no exceptions are output.

Now, trying to connect to the FTP fails. I suspect the reason is that the port 21 is not open on the firewall that protects azure websites and no traffic on that port is forwarded. Is there any way around this?

Connecting from the Website it self to the FTP server hosted in the job gives the following errors:

When connecting to 127.0.0.1

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions 127.0.0.1:21

When connecting using the websitename.azurewebsite.net on port 21 (from the website itself, that is hosting the FTP inside the webjob)

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond xx.xx.xx.xx:21

I would like to stick to the Azure Web Apps as much as possible to avoid having to manage VMs

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also open to the potential alternative approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Web Apps only support incoming traffic on ports 80 and 443. You will not be able to host ftp servers via web apps (aside from the built-in ftp server). You'd need to place the ftp server either in a VM or web/worker role (cloud service).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wish Azure would add that support in the future (if it is technically feasible). I love the hands off approach to deploying using Azure Websites and WebJobs - it keeps everything in the same place - without having to be an expert in securing a windows box.