# exposing kestrel server deployed as web job for external interaction

Tags: azure-webjobs, kestrel, azure-appservice

I have deployed an application hosting Kestrels server bindded to a specific port as web job .I want to access that port in order to have to access to APIs implemented in that application.

If I try to bind with port 443 it fails on other ports the server starts but cant interact with external requests.Is there any way I can expose this port to listen to incoming requests

Comment: Does my answer help you, or is there any inspiration?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: The problem was not solved using web job so I  kept the service on existing implementation i.e. VM ..Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web App only support port `443` and `80`. And webjob host in `Azure App Service`.

After a lot of searching for information and trying. **I can tell you with certainty that other ports cannot be used.**

For more details, you can read below post.

1. [Opening ports to Azure Web Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313892/opening-ports-to-azure-web-job)
2. [Is it possible to use an Azure Web Job to listen on a public socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47601783/is-it-possible-to-use-an-azure-web-job-to-listen-on-a-public-socket)

**The above is a statement of port restrictions in webjob.**

For you want webjob to monitor and process incoming requests, my suggestion is that webjob monitors ports `443` and `80` instead of binding. You can use `RawSocket`.

Monitor all requests, analyze whether the request content contains instructions that need to be executed, and then proceed to the next business operation.

If you already have completed project, you also can choose `VM` or `Cloud Services`.